# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "DEOA"

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I am working on an Instant Chat Application.I have used a panel of emoticons to send emoticons through my application.I am sending the unicode character of an emoji to server using following code.

```
String toServer = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(message);
```

When i am receiving messages from the server,I am decoding using following code:

```
 try {
                        String messageReceived = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(message);
                        String date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                        Long time = Long.parseLong(date);
                        String t = getDateFromTimestamp(time);
                        Log.e("TimeC", t);
                        Log.e("Date", date);
                        isSelf = true;
                        msg = new Bean_Message(userName, messageReceived, isSelf);
                        msg.setTime(t);
                        listBeanMessages.add(msg);
                        adapter_message.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        Log.e("Exception", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
```

I am getting NumberFormatException while decoding the Unicode.Log is given below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "DEOA"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
        at org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(StringEscapeUtils.java:331)
            at org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(StringEscapeUtils.java:287)
            at com.almabay.almachat.activity.SingleChatActivity.parseJsonFeed(SingleChatActivity.java:582)
            at com.almabay.almachat.activity.SingleChatActivity$MessageTask.onPostExecute(SingleChatActivity.java:517)
            at com.almabay.almachat.activity.SingleChatActivity$MessageTask.onPostExecute(SingleChatActivity.java:505)
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "DEOA"` DE**O**A is not a valid int. DE**0**A is.

Comment: Actually DEOA is what i am getting from server. I am getting the Unicode  \uD83D\uDEOA from the .I need to decode it to show its emoji using EmojiconTextView .

Comment: But "O" can't be interpreted as a number. "O" is different from "0". Similarly, "I" is different from "1"

Comment: I have manually send a unicode to server as i was trying something .So i guess i have written wrongly .Now what to do?

Comment: Correct what you send. And also check what you receive (I guess you can easily replace "O" with "0" and see what happens).

Comment: The problem is i am hitting the API to load old messages .This unicode is stored in the database.In my screen i am displaying old messages on the top half of the screen.This error is when i am loading old messages .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103720/discussion-between-deepakr-and-hrundi-v-bakshi).

Comment: Working now after deleting all d messages from the database.But the problem can reappear if user send the wrong unicode character

Comment: So correct the user "wrong unicode character".